# Doubleclicking SWF file leads to its contents expansion?

Tags: size, flash, symbols, fla

I am working on flash project. When i directly play my swf file by double clicking it, its contents i.e fla symbols and graphics used expands (size increases) abnormally, but when I generate swf with fla, I am getting normal result. 
I am confused, Please help me to get over.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a matter of stage.scaleMode, try changing the stage to the correct width/height and set the scaleMode to noScale. Should do the trick.

Here you can read about it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html